# Need to carry heavy load to Goa on charity mission

Tags: usa, luggage, india, freighter-travel

We are practicing medical doctors in America want to do charity work in Mumbai and Goa we need to bring with us medicines and food and clothing and shoes for our patients .Frieght is expensive we were wondering if we join Frieght ships and travel with them for say 10 to 15 days via sea will this arrangement more economical and efficient?

Comment: Given the apparently thriving pharmaceutical manufacturing industry in India wouldn't it be less expensive and more environmentally sustainable to get your medicines in India from an Indian manufacturer? The same could be said of clothing and shoes. Neighboring Sri Lanka and Bangladesh also have thriving textiles industries.  Much of my US-purchased wardrobe was manufactured in those countries.

Comment: What sort of medicine is it that you believe would be cheaper to transport from the US to India as opposed to purchasing locally?

Answer (score 1):

Use a cargo/container freight ship for all your cargo to Goa; and forget about it for at least a couple of weeks/months ( a quick google says it can take about 1 month+ from SF to Goa)

You should contact a broker specializing in that kind of shipping to take care of all the paper work, taxes and duties and customs and permits.

I would imagine bringing in medicine need special permits; and depending on the medicine type, you might even need a refrigerated container.

And for you and your colleagues, use normal transportation mode and plan to arrive within days your cargo clear custom in India and organize the transport from the port to your final destination.

As for the price, I don't have a clue; you need to contact a broker with the details of your cargo and decide what kind of shipping you really need (container, 1/2 container, refrigerated...).

Good luck with that.